# Giving Style To DIV"S on Master Pages

Tags: asp.net

Somethings wrong is happened here is I can't draw my css styles to my divs.
This is my code of Default.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MyMasterStyle.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="masterPagesExample.Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    Welcome to our web site.good news for it people,write here, that is <br />
Will help you to up to date your experiance.
</asp:Content>
```

And here is part of the css :

```
#footer 
{
    width:700px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color:#00ff00;
    color:#101010;
}
```

and here is the master page soruce file:

```
<div id="page_wrapper">

    <div id="header">
           <h1>Welcome To Our Website !</h1>
           <h3>World is in your hands...</h3>
           <br />
           <br />
    </div>
    <div id="post-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy</p>
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

In design view every things appears good . but when I run app , no css will apply.

Where is the problem ?

Should I set something in masterpage ?

I have linked the css file in the head of master page.

Comment: could you put the code where you linking the css in masterpage

Answer (score 1):

If your CSS page is linked from an external file, and you've specified the path in the `<link>` tag relatively (i.e. using `href="relative/path/to.css"`), it's possible that your content page can't find the CSS file.

Have you verified that it's being loaded when you run the app? Try viewing the source and making sure the CSS path is valid.

Comment: design view shows my styles very nice , in the browser ,  header style is nice but the footer not working

Comment: @Parkhid Design view is not be trusted in my experience.

Comment: oops, what should am i do >??

Comment: @Parkhid: Did you try this: "Try viewing the source and making sure the CSS path is valid."? And when I said viewing the source, I mean in your browser.